# API Call Data Issues with Passing to New View Controller - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, api, viewcontroller

I am building a swift app and hit an issue where the data I get back from an API call is not being passed to the view controller. I have uilabels all over the page and they do not update after the query is made like I intended. I am trying to present the aviation weather data from the user on the view controller *ReportViewController.*

I can get the data to fill labels on the WxViewController, but don't understand why I can't mirror the same code to have it display on the ReportViewController instead. I have tried copy/paste and removing the same code from the WxViewController as well as having it in both places, but the only place that updates the label is WxViewController (testTextLabel). Any help getting out of this endless cycle would be appreciated!

WxViewController

```
//
//  WxViewController.swift
//  AvWx Pro
//
//  Created by Grayson Bertaina on 9/21/20.
//

import UIKit

class WxViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, WeatherManagerDelegate {

    var weatherManager = WeatherManager()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var testTextField: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var stationSearch: UITextField!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        weatherManager.delegate = self
        stationSearch.delegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func searchPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        print(stationSearch.text!)
        stationSearch.endEditing(true)
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print(stationSearch.text!)
        stationSearch.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }
    
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if let station = stationSearch.text {
            weatherManager.fetchWeather(stationICAO: station)
        }

        stationSearch.text = ""
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if stationSearch.text != "" {
            return true
        } else {
            stationSearch.placeholder = "Type an ICAO"
            return false
        }
    }
    
    func didUpdateWeather(_ weatherManager: WeatherManager, weather: WeatherModel) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.testTextField.text = weather.flightConditions
        }
        print(weather.flightConditions)
        
        
        }
        
    
    
    func didFailWithError(error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }
    
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    
    
}
```

ReportViewController

```
//
//  ReportViewController.swift
//  AvWx Pro
//
//  Created by Grayson Bertaina on 9/22/20.
//

import UIKit

class ReportViewController: UIViewController, WeatherManagerDelegate {

    var weatherManager = WeatherManager()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var flightRulesTitleLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var flightRulesValueLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var visibilityValueLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var altimeterValueLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var cloudsTitleLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var cloudsType1Label: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var cloudsAltitude1Label: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var cloudsType2Label: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var cloudsAltitude2Label: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var cloudsType3Label: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var cloudsAltitude3Label: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var windGTextLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var windSpeedValueLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var windGustValueLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var windFromTextLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var windDirectionValueLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var remarksValueLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        weatherManager.delegate = self
        
    }
    

    func didUpdateWeather(_ weatherManager: WeatherManager, weather: WeatherModel) {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.flightRulesValueLabel.text = weather.flightConditions
            print(weather.flightConditions)
        }
        
        
    }
    
    func didFailWithError(error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }
    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    

}
```

WeatherManager

```
//
//  WeatherManager.swift
//  AvWx Pro
//
//  Created by Grayson Bertaina on 9/21/20.
//

import Foundation

protocol WeatherManagerDelegate : class {
    func didUpdateWeather(_ weatherManager: WeatherManager, weather: WeatherModel)
    func didFailWithError(error: Error)
}

struct WeatherManager {
    let weatherURL = "https://avwx.rest/api/metar/"
    
    weak var delegate : WeatherManagerDelegate?

    func fetchWeather (stationICAO: String) {
        let urlString = "\(weatherURL)\(stationICAO)?token=OVi45FiTDo1LmyodShfOfoizNe5m9wyuO6Mkc95AN-c"
        performRequest(with: urlString)
    }
    
    func performRequest (with urlString: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
                
            
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    self.delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error!)
                    return
                }
                
                if let safeData = data {
                    if let weather = self.parseJSON(safeData) {
                        self.delegate?.didUpdateWeather(self, weather: weather)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            task.resume()
            print(urlString)
            
            
            }
        }
    
    func parseJSON(_ weatherData: Data) -> WeatherModel? {
        
        
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: weatherData)
            
            
            
            let clouds = decodedData.clouds
            let lowCloudsType = (clouds.count > 0 ? clouds[0]?.type : nil) ?? "N/A"
            let midCloudsType = (clouds.count > 1 ? clouds[1]?.type : nil) ?? "N/A"
            let highCloudsType = (clouds.count > 2 ? clouds[2]?.type : nil) ?? "N/A"
            let lowCloudsAlt = (clouds.count > 0 ? clouds[0]?.altitude : nil) ?? 0
            let midCloudsAlt = (clouds.count > 1 ? clouds[1]?.altitude : nil) ?? 0
            let highCloudsAlt = (clouds.count > 2 ? clouds[2]?.altitude : nil) ?? 0
            let reportingStationVar = decodedData.station ?? "N/A"
            let windGustValue = decodedData.wind_gust?.value ?? 0
            let windSpeedValue = decodedData.wind_speed?.value ?? 0
            let windDirectionValue = decodedData.wind_direction?.value ?? 999
            let visibilityValue = decodedData.visibility?.value ?? 0
            let flightRulesValue = decodedData.flight_rules ?? "N/A"
            
            let weather = WeatherModel(lowestCloudsType: lowCloudsType , lowestCloudsAlt: lowCloudsAlt, middleCloudsType: midCloudsType , middleCloudsAlt: midCloudsAlt, highestCloudsType: highCloudsType , highestCloudsAlt: highCloudsAlt, reportingStation: reportingStationVar, windGust: windGustValue, windSpeed: windSpeedValue, windDirection: windDirectionValue, visibility: visibilityValue, flightRules: flightRulesValue)
            
            delegate?.didUpdateWeather(self, weather: weather)
            
            return weather
            
        } catch {
            delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error)
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```

WeatherData

```
//
//  WeatherData.swift
//  AvWx Pro
//
//  Created by Grayson Bertaina on 9/21/20.
//

import Foundation

struct WeatherData: Codable {
   
    
    let clouds: [Clouds?]
    let flight_rules: String?
    let remarks: String?
    let wind_speed: WindSpeed?
    let wind_gust: WindGust?
    let wind_direction: WindDirection?
    let visibility: Visibility?

    let station: String?
}



struct Clouds: Codable {
    let type: String
    let altitude: Int
}

struct WindSpeed: Codable {
    let value: Int
}

struct WindGust: Codable {
    let value: Int
}

struct WindDirection: Codable {
    let value: Int
}

struct Visibility: Codable {
    let value: Int
}
```

Again, I really appreciate the help! There are no errors when I run my code.

Comment: Where are you calling the fetch for the report vc?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that on the reportvc because the UITextField is on the WxViewController. That was my first instinct but I couldn't figure out how to get the user entry from WxViewController to the fetch query if I put it on the ReportViewController.

Comment: Unless you call the fetch, you'll never get the data! Try putting one in the ViewDidLoad on the report, you should see something.

Comment: When I go to add the call, since the call requires a "Station" input, how do I take the user entered station from WxViewController inside of the ```func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if let station = stationSearch.text {
            weatherManager.fetchWeather(stationICAO: station)
        }

        stationSearch.text = ""

    }``` to the ReportViewController?

Comment: without seeing how your app is organized, I can't tell you. Store the selected value somewhere? you can set the selection before you execute your segue.

Comment: I got it to work! Thank you so much. If you post that as an answer, I will mark as correct! :)